# Embedding N/H into N

Tags: group-theory

Let $N$ be a group and $H$ be a normal subgroup of $N$. Let $S$ be the set of cosets of $H$. Prove or disprove: we can find a representative in every element of $S$ and form a group isomorphic to $N/H$ when:

(i) $N$ is finite
(ii) $N$ infinite, $H$ may or may not be finite.

I think (i) is true using a greedy algorithm but I am not sure whether (ii) is true.

Comment: The magic words are "semidirect product".

Comment: Greedy algorithm gets you nothing. Broth statements are false.